# Runge kutta method for order 4 for ODE x'=f(t)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

Question: What is the simplified form of Runge kutta method when applied to order 4 for ODE x'=f(t)?

The runge kutta method is

$$k_1 = f(t_0,x(t_0))$$
$$k_2 = f(t_0+h/2,x(t_0)+k_1/2)$$
$$k_3 = f(t_0+h/2,x(t_0)hk_2/2)$$
$$k_4 = f(t_0+h,x(t_0)+k_3)$$
Then 
$$x(t_0+h)= x(t_0) + h\frac{k_1+2k_2+2k_3+k_4}{6}$$

How would I apply it to the ODE here? DO i expand taylor series like expand $x(t_0+h)= x(t_0) + h\frac{k_1+2k_2+2k_3+k_4}{6}$? thanks.

Comment: first line i added question: to make it more obvious

Comment: When $f$ is independent of $x$, it becomes the Simpson's 1/3 rule. I don't think you need to, or am able to simplify it further if you want to keep it as 4-th order. Because Simpson's 1/3 rule is already one of the simplest 4-th order integration method. Of course that depends on your definition of "simple".

Comment: I don't get your question. The method described in your question is explicit. So you can evaluate $k_i$ and the plug it into $k_{i+1}$ to evaluate $k_{i+1}$. What do you exactly mean with "apply" it to the ODE? At what point are you stuck?  Is velut's comment what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You just follow the equations.  You start at a time $t_0$, a position $x_0(t_0)$, and choose a step size $h$.  You now just compute each line in turn.  When you are done you are at time $t_1=t_0+h$ and (an approximation of) position $x_1(t_1)$.  Now take another step which might be at the same step size or not.  There is a nice discussion of how to choose the step size based on the desired error in section 17.2 of [Numerical Recipes](http://apps.nrbook.com/empanel/index.html#).  Other numerical analysis texts should have a section as well.